# bash: reading "at" result into variable

Tags: bash, output, at-job

I tried all variations and things I found on stackoverflow or Google, but for some reason the `at` bash command seems to do something different.

What I would like to do is to read the result of my scheduled command into a variable:

```
myVar=$(echo "echo 'Hello World'" | at now + 1 minute)
```

The `at` command prints out things like:

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 12 at Wed Mar 13 20:21:00 2024
```

I would expect to have this information in the `${myVar}` with the above, but it's not there. Anyone any idea how I can get the result from `at` into a variable?

And to be sure it has nothing to do with my `bash` version:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `at` writes that summary to standard error, not standard output.

Comment: Thanks, how would you figure that out (I mean just because it says `warning`)... anyways I used `myVar=$(echo "echo 'Hello World'" | at now + 1 minute 2>&1)` and it worked as expected! Thanks for the help!

Comment: The fact that it wasn't captured is generally the giveaway :) -- anything that still goes to output was either written to stderr or written direct to the TTY, and the TTY case is rare and generally only done when there's a specific good reason to do so (like making a password prompt difficult to intercept). stderr isn't just for errors -- it's for all "diagnostic content" per POSIX; basically anything/everything that's meant to inform a human operator vs being part of a program's "output" (whatever kind of output that program is written/designed to generate).

Comment: (Lots more things are "diagnostic" in that sense than someone might intuit -- for example, shell prompts are written to stderr, because they're there to tell the operator when the shell is ready for them to type a new command; diagnostic content not going to stdout is generally a Good Thing -- if you're writing `curl http://example.com/foo.csv > foo.csv`, f/e, you want curl's progress bar to be displayed to the user, not mixed into the CSV file's contents).